# Differentiate between same key values in a map

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to create a map in kotlin, where multiple key values may be null. For example:

```
val value1 = null
val errorValueForOne = ""

val value2 = "Toast"
val errorValueForTwo = ""

val value3 = null
val errorValueForThree = ""

val mappedValues = mapOf(
    value1 to errorValueForOne,
    value2 to errorValueForTwo,
    value3 to errorValueForThree
)
```

The problem is, when I print the map out, it just prints two values instead of three, because the two "null" keys are put together (which makes sense because it is the same key)

My question is now: Is it possible to solve this problem? Is a map the wrong data structure to solve this problem? My Idea would be to create a List<Map<String?,String>>, something like this:

```
val mappedList = listOf(
   mapOf(value1 to errorValueForOne),
   mapOf(value2 to errorValueForTwo),
   mapOf(value3 to errorValueForThree)
)
```

The Problem with this approach might be that this is slow and I have to recreate the list again and again

Comment: `Is a map the wrong data structure to solve this problem?` my opinion, probably. this is like providing the same string twice as a key and expecting it to not see this as one

Comment: How would you select which one errorValue your code should use? If map could store two values for one key, how to choose which one to use? I'm just trying to understand what problem you're trying to solve :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys in a map should be unique. I your case you want to insert null twice, this is impossible.

I would suggest to use data object or class with two properties and then keep list of them.
For example:

```
data class MyData (
    val key: String?,
    val value: String
) 

var myList: List<MyData> = //...
```

Comment: i think i prefer this option a bit more, instead of using a pair, because it allows you to easily scale your requirements in future - you can add more fields into your class if you needed to

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Map` is a wrong data structure for your use-case, `Map` allows unique keys , if you have `null` as key, you can use it at-most once, any further `null` keys will be overriding the existing `null` key value. You can may be create `List` of `Pairs`

```
val mappedValues 
        = listOf(Pair(value1, errorValueForOne), 
                 Pair(value2, errorValueForTwo), 
                 Pair(value3, errorValueForThree))
```

Comment: Which one is the faster option? Your Solution or artmans?

Comment: `Pair` makes sense as it is used for `key-value` in ideal scenarios

Comment: Pair does make sense, but if you need to add additional fields in future, you'll have to refactor quite a bit, where a custom class makes this easier, but, then again, nobody asked me :) both solutions equally valid, honestly

Comment: key will always be one, for value  if you want multiple props you can extend it to class inside Pair itself :)

Comment: I think I asked my question wrong. With "faster" I don't mean which one I can programm faster. I mean, which one is created faster by the compiler. I have to create this list again and again and therefore I am asking: Is it better to use a Pair or a custom dataclasss?

Comment: Also it doesn't matter what you use, performant wise both are equally inefficient vs map, `O(n)` for read

Comment: No difference in creation, as `Pair` is also `data class` with generics, only extra thing is it extends `Serializable`, one lesser class to create as Pair comes out of the box.

Comment: I think there is no difference in speed between custom data class or Pair, because Pair is also a data class in kotlin

Comment: And what might be a faster solution? Or am I limited to this?

Comment: Faster solution might be not to use multiple nulls and just use some other values to identify them , so you can keep using hashmap, also it depends on size of your list, if it is limited, just go with list of pairs. it still gives constant time

Comment: If you want to use same keys, then I know no way you can speed it up. If you could manage and use different keys, then I would suggest doing so and using `Map`

Comment: @rajan.kali second comment in a row saying the same thing with only seconds apart lol

Comment: No, it is unfortunately not possible to use different keys. Then I will stick with this solution, thanks